# Scala What is this "_1" in type?

Tags: scala

I would like to understand this error:

```
found   : row.type (with underlying type _#TableElementType)
required: _1#TableElementType
```

Looks like I was very close, but what is this "1" in `_1#TableElementType`? Can I convert one in the other?

**Edit**: useful bits of codes for context (Play + Slick):

```
abstract class GenericDAO[T <: AbstractTable[_]](...) {
  def table: TableQuery[T]
  def insert(model: T#TableElementType) = db run (table += model)
}

trait TableObject[T <: AbstractTable[_]] {
  def rowFromJson(jsObject: JsObject): T#TableElementType
  def dao(driver: JdbcProfile, db: Database): GenericDAO[T]
}

// Controller Action with an instance implementing `tableObject` above:
val tableObject = tableObjectFactory("test")
val row = tableObject.rowFromJson(request.body.asJson.get)
val dao = tableObject.dao(driver, db)  // tableObject has a DOA extending GenericDAO
dao.insert(row)
```

Example of `tableObject`:

```
object TestTable extends TableObject[Test] {
  def dao(driver: JdbcProfile, db: Database) = new TestDAO(driver, db)
  def rowFromJson(j: JsObject): TestRow = { TestRow(...) }
  class TestDAO(...) extends GenericDAO[Test](driver, db) { ... }
}
```

I use a factory to get the right one from the url:

```
object TableObjectFactory {
  def tableObjectFactory(name: String) = {
    name match {
      case "test" => TestTable
      case "projects" => ProjectsTable
      case "people" => PeopleTable
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: I added code providing the context.

Comment: What exactly is `tableObject`'s type? Are you defining it as `val tableObject = TestTable`?

Comment: It says "`TableObject[_ >: Test with Projects with People with ... <: Test.profile.Table[_ >: TestRow with ProjectsRow with PeopleRow with ...]]`". I added my factory function to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't explain much, it works if I make the DAO parse the request body and insert, instead of producing the row object separately and applying one of the DAO's methods on it.

I got all kinds of similar errors with names such as `_$1#TableElementType`, `_1$u#TableElementType` etc., but I think they are compiler aliases for different instances of the same class.

So the solution was to do

```
val j: JsValue = request.body.asJson.get
val tableObject: TableObject[_] = tableObjectFactory(table)
val dao = tableObject.dao(driver, db)
val res: Future[Int] = dao.insert(j)
```

where this new `insert` method now is *abstract* in `GenericDAO`, and in the concrete implementations takes a `JsValue` and parses it, then inserts:

```
class TestDAO(override val driver: JdbcProfile, override val db: Database) extends GenericDAO[Test](driver, db) {
  import this.driver.api._

  val table = TableQuery[Test]

  //def insert(model: TestRow) = db run (table += model)   // NO!

  def insert(j: JsValue): Future[Int] = {
    val row = TestRow(
      (j \ "id").as[Int],
      (j \ "name").as[String],
      (j \ "value").as[Float],
      (j \ "other").as[String]
    )
    db run (table += row)
  }
}
```

At the same time, it makes Play forms completely useless, which is a good thing anyway.